# R summary of data table

Tags: r, data.table

How would you show the short condensed version of a fairly short(~40) row data table? I know that for very long data tables it will automatically show this shortened version that shows the first and last 5 rows. However with shortish data tables, it will just show the entire data table. Is there any way to force the short version?

Example of abbreviated version:

```
         tpl       motif                 refName strand base score ipdRatio coverage
  1:    7098 ATCAAGGTCCT scf7180000000004|quiver      0    A    64    6.347       38
  2:   46246 ATCAATCGCCT scf7180000000004|quiver      0    A   213    6.371      148
  3:   57947 ATCATATTCCT scf7180000000004|quiver      0    A   226    6.464      147
  4:   59260 ATCAATTACCT scf7180000000004|quiver      0    A   203    5.715      120
  5:   72361 ATCATGTTCCT scf7180000000004|quiver      0    A   205    6.449      144
 ---                                                                                
537: 2835276 ATCATTTGCCT scf7180000000004|quiver      1    A   201    6.329      153
538: 2837973 ATCAATTGCCT scf7180000000004|quiver      1    A   215    5.982      146
539: 2842508 ATCAAATACCT scf7180000000004|quiver      1    A   196    4.241      157
540: 2844725 ATCGTACTCCT scf7180000000004|quiver      1    A   227    6.123      140
541: 2847076 ATCAGTACCCT scf7180000000004|quiver      1    A   158    5.990      120
```

Comment: See [FAQ 2.11](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf#page10).

Comment: I want to be able to present the table in exactly the same format as the abbreviated version. including the dashed lines and keeping the rows numbered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the "summarized" version to be shown for data tables that are 10 or more rows in size, try `options(datatable.print.nrows=10)`

The default value for that option is 50. Read more about it in [Data Table FAQ 2.11](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf)

Comment: If you just need to do it once and want to leave the settings alone: `print(DT,nrows=10)`